# webpack angular and sass issue when trying to serve or build a template project

Tags: angular, webpack, sass, node-sass

I have been using this material angular template as a base for an admin project - after a couple months of development - my system started erroring when I tried ng serve, or ng build - the screen throws numerous errors (basically the same error for every module or template that calls the scss templates - meaning almost all of them.

Here is the beginning (and end) of the error, hopefully it will ring a bell with someone.

```
ERROR in ./src/styles.scss (./node_modules/raw-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--14-3!./src/styles.scss)
Module build failed:
@import "src/@fuse/scss/fuse";
...

^
  File to import not found or unreadable: src/@fuse/scss/fuse.
  in C:\www\app\src\@fuse\components\navigation\navigation.component.scss (

line 1, column 1)
ERROR in ./src/app/main/admin/my-profile/my-profile.component.scss
Module build failed:
undefined
^
  File to import not found or unreadable: src/@fuse/scss/fuse.
  in C:\www\app\src\app\main\admin\my-profile\my-profile.component.scss (line 2, column 1)
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

Things I have tried:

```
1) moving my project up the dir structure to reduce path length 
2) blowing out package lock and node_modules and reinstalling -  
3) deleting node-sass from npm-cache 
4) npm rebuild node-sass 
5) npm audit fix 
6) doing a regex in win 10 home to LongPathsEnabled=1

7) TOTALLY new install of win 10 home, on brand new SSD - fresh install of nodeJS 10, Angular CLI, and ONLY this RAW template no modifications 
(this was a planned upgrade, not a drastic hail-mary, but I was hopeful that it might help this issue). No luck  - same issue.
```

Other developers are NOT having this issue - which means they can commit to a repo, and work, while when I pull (or even try a direct install from the vendor) I cannot compile...and that means I cannot work

ANY HELP OR IDEAS ARE GREATLY APPRECIATED

Environment:

```
Win 10 home 
Angular CLI: 6.0.8
Node: 10.14.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.0.9
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer    0.6.8
@angular-devkit/core               0.6.8
@angular-devkit/schematics         0.6.8
@angular/cdk                       6.3.3
@angular/cli                       6.0.8
@angular/flex-layout               6.0.0-beta.16
@angular/material                  6.3.3
@angular/material-moment-adapter   6.3.3
@ngtools/webpack                   6.0.8
@schematics/angular                0.6.8
@schematics/update                 0.6.8
rxjs                               6.2.1
typescript                         2.7.2
webpack                            4.8.3
```

The package.json looks like this.

```
{
  "name": "fuse",
  "version": "6.2.4",
  "license": "https://themeforest.net/licenses/terms/regular",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --open",
    "start-hmr": "ng serve --configuration hmr --source-map=false --hmr-warning=false",
    "start-hmr-sourcemaps": "ng serve --configuration hmr --source-map=true --hmr-warning=false",
    "build": "node --max_old_space_size=6144 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --dev",
    "build-stats": "node --max_old_space_size=6144 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --dev --stats-json",
    "build-prod": "node --max_old_space_size=6144 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod",
    "build-prod-stats": "node --max_old_space_size=6144 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --stats-json",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "bundle-report": "webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/stats.json"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "1.0.0-beta.3",
    "@angular/animations": "6.0.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "6.3.3",
    "@angular/common": "6.0.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "6.0.9",
    "@angular/core": "6.0.9",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "6.0.0-beta.16",
    "@angular/forms": "6.0.9",
    "@angular/http": "6.0.9",
    "@angular/material": "6.3.3",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "6.3.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "6.0.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.0.9",
    "@angular/router": "6.0.9",
    "@ngrx/effects": "6.0.1",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "6.0.1",
    "@ngrx/store": "6.0.1",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "6.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "10.0.2",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "8.1.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "13.0.1",
    "@swimlane/ngx-dnd": "4.0.0",
    "@types/prismjs": "1.9.0",
    "angular-calendar": "0.25.2",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "0.6.0",
    "chart.js": "2.7.2",
    "classlist.js": "1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "2.5.7",
    "d3": "5.5.0",
    "guid-typescript": "1.0.9",
    "hammerjs": "2.0.8",
    "lodash": "4.17.10",
    "moment": "2.22.2",
    "ng2-charts": "1.6.0",
    "ngrx-store-freeze": "0.2.4",
    "ngx-color-picker": "6.5.0",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "1.0.10",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "1.4.0",
    "prismjs": "1.15.0",
    "rxjs": "6.2.1",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.2.1",
    "web-animations-js": "2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.6.8",
    "@angular/cli": "6.0.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "6.0.9",
    "@angular/language-service": "6.0.9",
    "@angularclass/hmr": "2.1.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.3",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.111",
    "@types/node": "8.9.5",
    "codelyzer": "4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "karma": "1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "protractor": "5.3.2",
    "ts-node": "5.0.1",
    "tslint": "5.9.1",
    "typescript": "2.7.2",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "2.13.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reinstall of your OS was a little over the top I think.

As you can see in your error:

```
in C:\www\app\src\@fuse\components\navigation\navigation.component.scss (
```

The app is looking in the wrong directory since the `@fuse` folder should be in `node_modules`

If you want to include the stylesheet in your angular build, try adding it to `angular.json`. In the configs you should find a row where your `style.scss` is included. Just add the external stylesheet there:

```
        "styles": [
          "./node_modules/@fuse/scss/fuse.scss",
          "src/styles.scss"
        ],
```

Then restart the CLI.

If you want to import it within a stylesheet itself, try doing this:

`@import "~@fuse/scss/fuse"`

For global styles however I recommend the first variant.

Comment: I will certianly try that. thanks.
(as mentioned the OS reinstall was a planned HD swap... :) )